# Giving Stackoverflow Exception on input focus React-Native

Tags: react-native, exception, stack-overflow

i am new to react native and i'm having an exception when input field focus. 
This is the screen that have two tabs. 
[Screen Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyQtd.png)

and in the second tab i'm going to load list of data fetch from Rest API. This is where i got this exception

[Component A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2U9n.png)

and here is the component that contains the input field with callback functions

[Component B that imported to A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TIBf.png)

i am getting below exception when i press the input field to type something.
[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OJt2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue, I did two things and the project did its magic I don't know the reason but it worked for me

1. Changed all my functions to arrow functions
2. initialized all my states by some value.